# CSS/HTML can't seem to center menu header

Tags: html, css, header, center, dreamweaver

I need help centering the menu on CSS...if I could get some help that would be great! I've tried lots of methods but it just floats left no matter what basically. If I add right: 50% and left 50% it centers but then there is white space to the right of the page. The CSS is really messy because I tried messing around with the settings to make it centered..

Here is the CSS

```
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#menu-button {
height: auto;
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
border: 0;
list-style: none;
line-height: 1;
display: block;
position: relative;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: auto;
}
#cssmenu ul {
clear:left;
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position:relative;
text-align:center;  
}
#cssmenu ul li {
display:block;
float:left;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position:relative;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
text-align:center;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
display: none;
text-align: center;
width: auto;
}
#cssmenu {
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2); *Opacity*
line-height: 1;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
opacity: 1;
position: relative;
background-color: #00a5d4;
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

```css
    #cssmenu,
    #cssmenu ul li a,
    #menu-button {
 height: auto;
 margin: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 border: 0;
 list-style: none;
 line-height: 1;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: auto;
    }
    #cssmenu ul {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center; 
    }
    #cssmenu ul li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    }
    #cssmenu:after,
    #cssmenu > ul:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    text-align:center;
    }
    #cssmenu #menu-button {
 display: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: auto;
    }
    #cssmenu {
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2); *Opacity*
 line-height: 1;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 1;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #00a5d4;
    }
```

```html
    <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: so you just want the text to be in the center of the page?

Comment: Yep, found a solution thanks to the answers below!

Comment: I wish I could checkmark every comment on here, I really appreciate it guys. If anyone was wondering, changed some CSS rules basically and had some contradicting themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/bthb0y7g/1/

< li > changes to:

`display:inline-block;`

and remove left floats from everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CAPABILITIES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">RFQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
text-align:center;
}
#nav li {
display:inline;
}
#nav a {
text-decoration:none; 
padding:0 30px; /* variable width */
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eo84bgeh/2/)

You could even style it with a nice simple theme like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eo84bgeh/4/)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a centered menu: http://jsfiddle.net/24fwb5uv/6/
It should be relevant to you. The important stylings are a ul that takes up full width, with text within it aligned center. LI elements should be displayed inline and links should also be displayed inline. Note this does make things harder if you wanted to float things anywhere but it is a way to get a centered menu if you aren't too fussy about things.
Here is the relevant code:

```
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
</ul>

ul {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

li {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

a {
    display:inline;
}
```

I see that you have a wrapper around your menu, I would be careful that the wrapper takes up full width to let the ul take up full width. Make sure the css is "reset" then you won't have to specify margin:0; padding:0; in your css or worry about styles inherent to browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll keep in mind about the wrapper in the future.